# How to check and change name button in C# Windows Phone

Tags: c#, button, windows-phone

I have a problem, I'm making an easy game noughts and crosses on Windows Phone with Buttons:

```
<Button x:Name="ba0" Content=" " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="126" Margin="37,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="126" Click="a0"/>
```

I would like to change the content of the button if on the button there's " " and not to change if there's "X" or "O". I wrote something like that:

```
public void a0(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (ba0.Content == " ")
        ba0.Content = "X";
    else
         return;
}
```

But it doesn't work properly. Any idea?

Comment: Well, it doens't work, When there's space or there's "O" or "X" when I clock on the button nothing's happend (just regular click and no X)

Comment: Try code from my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

> Convert the content into string type and also trim the value.

```
public void a0(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(ba0.Content).Trim()))
                ba0.Content = "X";
            else
                return;
        }
```

> or check for white spaces

```
public void a0(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var content = Convert.ToString(ba0.Content);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
            ba0.Content = "X";
        else
            return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
<Button x:Name="ba0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="126" Margin="37,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="126" Click="a0"/>

public void a0(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(ba0.Content)))
        ba0.Content = "X";
    else
        return;
}
```

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments and also cannot convert object to string but I start to think in that way, thanks :)